# Yahoo YUI library CustomEvent class - subscribe() and fire()

Tags: javascript, yui

I am fairly new to javascript and using the YUI yahoo library.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.CustomEvent.html

I am trying to understand the subscribe and fire methods in a CustomEvent class. I have two questions regarding these

1. When the fire method is called. Does it fire all the functions that are subscribed to the event?
2. How do I fire an individual event? The subscribe method takes the parameter "obj  An object to be passed along when the event fires." so is there
   a way I can fire only this particular object?

Correct me if I misunderstand anything in the CustomEvent. :)

Answer (score 0):

> When the fire method is called. Does it fire all the functions that
>   are subscribed to the event?

The custom event (publisher) fires without caring who is listening (subscriber). 
Calling the fire() method causes all the listener methods to get fired.

> How do I fire an individual event?

You fire an individual event using :

```
var onCustomEvent = new YAHOO.util.CustomEvent('onCustomEvent');
onCustomEvent.fire();
```

> The subscribe method takes the parameter "obj An object to be passed along when the event fires." so
>   is there a way I can fire only this particular object?

You can fire the customEvent not the object ,
passing objects is used to pass arguments so they can be accessed in the subscribe method :

```
onCustomEvent.fire({action:'fire'});
onCustomEvent.subscribe(method);
function method(event, arguments, obj) {
     var action= args[0].action;//action contains fire  
}
```

event returns the name of the custom event
arguments is the set of arguments that are passed in the fire event
obj is the argument that is passed in the subscribe method.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new project, you should use [YUI3](http://yuilibrary.com/). Then you might benefit from [this documentation](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event-custom/).